# How to print string version of item in list python

Tags: python

```
def calorie():
    protein = 0
    fat = 0
    carb = 0
    tlist = [protein, fat, carb]
    for i in tlist:
        print('Enter food ' +  str(i))
        i = input()
    print(protein)
    print(carb)
    print(fat)

calorie()
```

right now it prints 'enter food 0'
I want it to loop and ask each time for protein fat and carb and then save it so i can put it into a database later. The code i have right now is 4 different def that points to protein then carb and so on however after thinking about it i thought it would be easier to just loop it in 1 single def however i cant get it to work. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you mean: `tlist = ['protein', 'fat', 'carb']`?

Comment: Consider using a dictionary: `tlist = {'protein': 0, 'fat': 0, 'carb': 0}`

Answer (score 2):

It prints `enter food 0` because by writing `for i in tlist` you are not iterating over the names of those variables but instead their value. `protein`, `fat`, and `carb` each have a value of 0, which is what Python prints.

Try using a dictionary?

```
calorie = {'protein': 0, 'fat': 0, 'carb': 0}

for key in calorie:
    value = input(f"Enter value of {key}: ")
    calorie[key] = int(value)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `for key in calorie:`?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I only learned dictionaries 2-3days back i should really start using it more

Answer (score 0):

`do you wan't tlist = ['protein', 'fat', 'carb'] this thing as a loop and you will enter how much amount specific things present in food.`

```
def calorie():
    protein = 0
    fat = 0
    carb = 0
    
    u=input("enter food name") #here you type food which detailed you wana insert.
    tlist = ['protein', 'fat', 'carb']
    for i in tlist:
        s=input("enter {} value in gm".format(i))
        print(f" {u} has {s} gm of {i}") #here it print amount nutrient the food has
```

`i hope it will resolve your problem`